# Easiest way to render 3D Points on Screen (C++ Windows Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rendering

My first posting so please be gentle.

Background: I have a very strong C++ Background.  I'm familiar with all the stuff that is native to C++ as well as the standard template library (STL).  I have done some graphics stuff in the past, but it almost always is messy and hacked together, has to include DLL files, etc...

Here's what I need to do and I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Given an array of 3D Points, I want to render them to the screen.  I also want to be able to rotate the viewport around.  I just want to be able to see the 3D Points that make up a model and I want to be able to view them from different angles.  I'll fill up the array of points myself (such as loading them from a text file).

The sad thing is, I know all the math to make this happen.  I've done it before from scratch, but, every few years something lame happens like DirectX updates, or I have to use the latest version of Visual Studio, and then my old code that worked well no longer does.

I just need to quickest way that I can render 3D points to a screen using C++.  Thank you very much.  Obviously I have to use some API or something to make it work like DirectX or OpenGL.  I'm hoping that maybe there's some system I've never used before that will just let me call a function such as "DrawPoint(x,y,z)" and I can call it a day.

So, my question is, if in my C++ code I have a big array of 3D Points and the (x,y,z) position of a camera and the vector that the camera is facing, what's the easiest way to render this (Using Windows7 or Windows8 and C++ and Visual Studio 2010).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need code to set up the camera and model matrices, as well as the projection matrices. The fixed function pipeline of OpenGL can help with that.

The camera is basically the view matrix, and combined with the 3D points will make up the model view matrix.

If you were to use OpenGL, you could use something like `gluLookAt(...)' from the GLU library for the camera.. In order to add the 3D points in the rendering part of the code, you could just use the fixed function pipeline where you draw the points (although modern OpenGL has moved onto using shaders, it should suffice), so something like:

```
void draw(){
    glColor3f(r,g,b);      // the r,g,b colour of the points
    glPointSize(size);     // where size indicates the size of the point
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);    // where x,y,z denotes the point position in 3D space
    glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
    .
    .
    glVertex3f(xn, yn, zn);
    glEnd();
}
```

There's a lot of material to cover here to create a 3D rendering application, and I'm not clear from your post how much of the code you may have already implemented.

To make it easier, there's a good resource available [here](http://songho.ca/opengl/index.html) that I've followed over quite some time, it has a great set of OpenGL notes.

If you look at the Matrix4 class notes, and download the 'matrix.zip' tutorial source code from there, it's pretty much what you would want. Just replace the code in the `drawModel()` function in the 'main.cpp' file with the code above to load your 3D points from file. Also, make sure the GLUT library folder is included in the VS project properties.

I'd also suggest going through those tutorials and notes, they are pretty concise, well structured and cover most of the basics of OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll give OpenGL and GLUT a try.  Thank you for the link to the notes as well.  Have a great day ccoder83!